# Recursive Determinant

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, recursion

The following code I devised to compute a [determinant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant):

```
module MatrixOps where

determinant :: (Num a, Fractional a) => [[a]] -> a
determinant [[x]] = x
determinant mat =
 sum [s*x*(determinant (getRest i mat)) | i <- [0..n-1], let x = (head mat) !! i
                                                             s = (-1)^i]
 where n = length $ head mat

getRest :: (Num a, Fractional a) => Int -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
getRest i mat = removeCols i (tail mat)

removeCols :: (Num a, Fractional a) => Int -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
removeCols _ [] = []
removeCols i (r:rs) = [r !! j | j <- [0..n-1], j /= i] : removeCols i rs
 where n = length r
```

I have a few general questions about the style of my code and practices:

- Is a very "Haskell" solution? I come from an OOP background and I am still learning functional programming.
- Is there a better way to space this out? I feel like some of the code is not very readable (this may just be because I am new), especially the definition of `determinant mat = ...`
- Is this code considerably "clean?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a few thoughts:

- Your method (IIUC) is conceptually correct, but has computation complexity *O(n!)* where *n* is the dimension of a given matrix. If you need better complexity (polynomial in *n*), you have to use another solution, such as using PLU decomposition described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Calculation).
- Be aware that since Haskell lists are essentially linked lists, getting *i*-th element using `(!!)` takes *O(i)*. So your code

  ```
  [r !! j | j <- [0..n-1], j /= i]
  ```

  has *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* complexity. You could express it in *O(n)* for example using [`splitAs`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v%3asplitAt) as

  ```
  let (left, right) = splitAt i r
   in left ++ (tail right)
  ```

  The same applies for `i <- [0..n-1], let x = (head mat) !! i`. You could do something like

  ```
  (i, x) <- zip [0..] (head mat)
  ```

  instead.

Comment: @mjgpy3 to add the oscillating sign there, `(i, sx) <- zip [0..] (zipWith (*) (cycle [1,-1]) $ head mat)` can be used. Or `(zipWith ($) (cycle [id, negate]) ...)`.